# SetInterval e reinicio

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `setInterval` com um intervalo de 2 segundos.
Preciso parar esse intervalo em certo momento e começá-lo de novo com um novo tempo.

**Escopo**
Faço um AJAX dentro do setInterval. Logo quando a resposta do AJAX for success (por exemplo), ele repete o intervalo novamente. Se for error, ele para o intervalo, muda o tempo do intervalo, e reinicia ele novamente.

Eu consegui fazer o seguinte até o momento:

```
var TempoRequest = 2200;
var Ativo = true;
if(Ativo === true){
    VerificaChat = setInterval( function(){
        if(acao){

        //repete o intervalo dnv

        }else{
            var Ativo = false;
            var TempoRequest = 15000;
            clearInterval(VerificaChat);
        }

    }, TempoRequest );
}
```

Comment: Primeiro preciso saber em que momento você quer que ele pare e em que momento seja adicionado um novo tempo? Fica muito vago dessa forma que você perguntou, posso parar com click ou passar de mouse, como quer parar setinterval e como quer reinicia-lo com novo tempo? Qual sua ideia?

Comment: É que tipo eu faço um AJAX dentro desse setInterval. Logo quando a resposta do data do AJAX for success (por exemplo), ele repete o intervalo denovo. Se for error, ele para o intervalo, muda o tempo do intervalo, e reinicia ele novamente. Entendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz algo bem simples aqui, veja se te ajuda.

```
  tempo = 2000; //crio variável global para controlar o tempo,
  number = 1; //essa variavel e apenas pra imprimir e controlar o incremento, mas no seu caso vai ser controlado pelo sucesso do AJAX

  setInterval(function(){
    if (number>0 && number<5) {
      document.write(number);
      number++;
    }else{
      document.write("-")
      number = 1;
      tempo += 100; //nessa parte eu apenas incrementei o tempo da variavel, mas se vc quiser pode resetar ela ou criar modo dinâmico para setar um tempo.
    }
  },tempo);
```